# Probability of 2 consecutive 6 in die rolling experience using combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There's this question:
You roll a die three times, what's the probability of getting 2 sixes in a row?

I have a solution for the problem that says: either getting 2 sixes in a row (first pair) or getting 2 sixes in a row (last pair), or getting 3 sixes in a row.

Since the first two cases get: 1/6 * 1/6 * 5/6 * 2
Then the last case: 1/6 * 1/6 * 1/6
This gives a probability of 11/216.

My first try on this exercise I wanted to use combinatorics.

My intuition led me to calculate all the possible outcomes which is 6^3 = 216 (6 numbers possible, 3 times)

This gives the denominator. Yet I've been stuck to find the number of favorable outcomes (nominator) using combinatorics. I understand that it is:
(6,6, 1–5) which gives 5 combinations or
(1—5, 6,6) which gives again 5 combinations or
(6,6,6) which is 1 combination

this gives a probability of 11/216.

But I can't find a mathematical formula that fits, and in a case where the combinations are too big, I wouldn't have found it.

Can someone tell me the way to solve this using combinatorics formula for any n and p?

Comment: You already used combinatorics!  You seem to have a generalization of this problem in mind, but there are many different ways it could be generalized.  What is yours?

Comment: I wanted to generalize this problem to any n number of rolls. What would be the probability to get p consecutive outcomes. 
For example, throw the dice 10 times, what is the proba of getting number "5" 6 consecutive times.

Comment: Okay: so please state that in your post itself.  I suspect we might already have a thread that answers this: your question is about the chances of *runs* in a series of coin flips.  (The "coin" in your case has a $1/6$ chance of landing on the chosen number and $5/6$ chance of not.)  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332600/probability-of-runs asks the same question, but has no effective answer (yet).  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362470 has two computing answers but no formulas. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158490 is related, with a good answer.